# Angular Checkbox Filters uncheckedAll

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-change

How do I create a button that will uncheck all checkboxes in this filter?

Please check this `[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/65Pyj/)`

Comment: Can you please update your question in detail here?

Answer (score 1):

Added few lines in your code
In Controller:

```
   $scope.ckB = function(){
        $scope.first= false;
        $scope.second=false;
        $scope.third=false;
        $scope.colourIncludes = [];
    }
```

Changes in html:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="first" ng-click="includeColour('Red')"/> Red</br>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="second" ng-click="includeColour('Orange')"/> Orange</br>
    <input type="checkbox"  ng-model="third" ng-click="includeColour('Yellow')"/> Yellow</br>
    <button ng-click="ckB()">Click</button>
```

Here is [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rx8cez2f/3/)
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the html code to include a ng-repeat loop.
This will ensure that in `checkAll()` you don't have to refer to each checkbox by its name unlike in the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28515461/4975444) by Deep.
Each of the element has an embedded ng-click attribute.

```
<!-- Start : Changed ng-repeat loop -->
<div ng-repeat="f in fruits">
    <input type="checkbox" 
            ng-click="includeColour(f.colour);"
            ng-model="f.selected">{{f.colour}}</input>
</div>
<!-- End : Changed ng-repeat loop -->
```

Modified the checkAll function in controller.

```
 $scope.checkAll = function () {
                               $scope.colourIncludes = [];
                               angular.forEach($scope.fruits, function (f) {
                                    f.selected = true;
                                    //to set filter dump
                                    $scope.colourIncludes.push(f.colour);
                                    });

                               };
```

Here is the JSFiddle Demo : [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/dineshchitlangia/0u7h241a/)